# SDL_Rect (SDL 2.0) Unexpected values from using SDL_Rect

Tags: c++, class, sdl, rect

The title may be a bit weird as I am not 100% sure about the main source of the problem.

A bit of background: I am making a program for inventory management at home

The Problem: I have a class called 'addItemForm' which is is intended to create an item as the name suggests. However, the problem lies within.

To render each specific individual part of the form I have create a few SDL_Rects to contain the coordinates for the rendering of each texture:

```
SDL_Rect TformBackgroundRect;
SDL_Rect TinputBox;
SDL_Rect TinputBox2;
SDL_Rect TinputBox3;
SDL_Rect TinputNameRect;
SDL_Rect TinputQuantRect;
SDL_Rect TinputUnitRect;
```

however, when I tried to use these (after they had been initialised in the constructor) nothing was rendered on screen. What I did then was create SDL_Rects in the constructor and then do this:

```
formBackgroundRect = TformBackgroundRect;
inputBox = TinputBox;
inputBox2 = TinputBox2;
inputBox3 = TinputBox3;
inputNameRect = TinputNameRect;
inputQuantRect = TinputQuantRect;
inputUnitRect = TinputUnitRect;
```

However, this did not work either. When I tried to do some collision detection it did not work either. I printed the x value for inputBox (inputBox.x) and it gave me a valuse of -8589993460!?!?

Ok, what I wrote is probably gibberish to most people so what i will do is post the code for my addItemForm class below:

addItemForm.h

```
class addItemForm
{
public:
int xPos;
int yPos;

//These are the values for the width and height of the different textures.
int fbtWidth, fbtHeight;
int iFtWidth, iFtHeight;
int iNtWidth, iNtHeight;
int iQtWidth, iQtHeight;
int iUtWidth, iUtHeight;


SDL_Color fontColor;

TTF_Font* formFont;


SDL_Texture* formBackgroundTexture;
SDL_Texture* inputFieldTexture;


SDL_Texture* inputNameText;
SDL_Texture* inputQuantityText;
SDL_Texture* inputUnitText;

SDL_Rect formBackgroundRect;
SDL_Rect inputBox;
SDL_Rect inputBox2;
SDL_Rect inputBox3;
SDL_Rect inputNameRect;
SDL_Rect inputQuantRect;
SDL_Rect inputUnitRect;

SDL_Rect TformBackgroundRect;
SDL_Rect TinputBox;
SDL_Rect TinputBox2;
SDL_Rect TinputBox3;
SDL_Rect TinputNameRect;
SDL_Rect TinputQuantRect;
SDL_Rect TinputUnitRect;

std::string inputNameString;
std::string inputQuantString;
std::string inputUnitString;

addItemForm(int x, int y);
~addItemForm();

void loadTextures();
void render();
void update(int x, int y, SDL_Event e);

void inputValuestoField(int x, int y, SDL_Event e);

void free();

private:

};
```

addItemForm.cpp

```
Button addItemButton(72, 65);

Button cancelEntry(383, 310);

bool isViewable = false;

addItemForm::addItemForm(int x, int y)
{
    xPos = x;
    yPos = y;



    formBackgroundTexture = NULL;
    inputFieldTexture = NULL;

    inputNameText = NULL;
    inputQuantityText = NULL;
    inputUnitText = NULL;



    fbtWidth = 0;
    fbtHeight = 0;
    iFtWidth = 0; 
    iFtHeight = 0;
    iNtWidth = 0; 
    iNtHeight = 0;
    iQtWidth = 0; 
    iQtHeight = 0;
    iUtWidth = 0; 
    iUtHeight = 0;

    formFont = TTF_OpenFont("media/cambria.ttf", 15);

    //The rects which will dictate where the textures are displayed onto the screen
    formBackgroundRect;
    inputBox;
    inputBox2;
    inputBox3;
    inputNameRect;
    inputQuantRect;
    inputUnitRect;


    //Defining the font colour:
    fontColor;
    fontColor.r = 0;
    fontColor.b = 0;
    fontColor.g = 0;
    fontColor.a = 0;

    addItemButton.loadFromFile("media/buttonAddItem.png");
    cancelEntry.loadFromFile("media/buttonCancelEntry.png");
}
void addItemForm::loadTextures()
{
    SDL_Surface* loadedSurface = NULL;

    //loading Images

    loadedSurface = IMG_Load("media/addItemForm/itemFormBG.png");
    if(loadedSurface == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could Not load Image: itemFormBG\n");
        printf("Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }
    else
    {
        SDL_SetColorKey(loadedSurface, SDL_TRUE, SDL_MapRGB(loadedSurface->format, 0, 0xFF, 0xFF) );
        formBackgroundTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(gRenderer, loadedSurface);
        fbtWidth = loadedSurface->w;
        fbtHeight = loadedSurface->h;
        loadedSurface = NULL;

    }


    loadedSurface = IMG_Load("media/addItemForm/inputTextField.png");
    if(loadedSurface == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not load Image: inputTextField.png\n");
        printf("Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }
    else
    {
        SDL_SetColorKey(loadedSurface, SDL_TRUE, SDL_MapRGB(loadedSurface->format, 0, 0xFF, 0xFF) );
        inputFieldTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(gRenderer, loadedSurface);
        iFtWidth = loadedSurface->w;
        iFtHeight = loadedSurface->h;
        loadedSurface = NULL;
    }

    //Loading text

    SDL_Texture* tmpTextTexture = NULL;
    std::string textArray[3] = {"Item Name:", "Quantity:", "Unit:"};
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
            loadedSurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(formFont, textArray[i].c_str(), fontColor);
            tmpTextTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(gRenderer, loadedSurface);
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0:
                    inputNameText = tmpTextTexture;
                    iNtWidth = loadedSurface->w;
                    iNtHeight = loadedSurface->h;
                case 1:
                    inputQuantityText = tmpTextTexture;
                    iQtWidth = loadedSurface->w;
                    iQtHeight = loadedSurface->h;
                case 2:
                    inputUnitText = tmpTextTexture;
                    iUtWidth = loadedSurface->w;
                    iUtHeight = loadedSurface->h;
            }

            loadedSurface = NULL;
            tmpTextTexture = NULL;

    }


    SDL_FreeSurface(loadedSurface);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(tmpTextTexture);
}

void addItemForm::render()
{
    SDL_Rect TformBackgroundRect = { xPos, yPos, fbtWidth, fbtHeight};
    SDL_Rect TinputBox = {xPos + 127, yPos + 72, iFtWidth, iFtHeight};
    SDL_Rect TinputBox2 = {xPos + 127, yPos + 122, iFtWidth, iFtHeight};
    SDL_Rect TinputBox3 = {xPos + 127, yPos + 165, iFtWidth, iFtHeight};
    SDL_Rect TinputNameRect = {xPos + 15 , yPos + 71, iNtWidth, iNtHeight};
    SDL_Rect TinputQuantRect = {xPos + 15, yPos + 121, iQtWidth, iQtHeight};
    SDL_Rect TinputUnitRect = {xPos  + 15, yPos + 164, iUtWidth, iUtHeight};  

    formBackgroundRect = TformBackgroundRect;
    inputBox = TinputBox;
    inputBox2 = TinputBox2;
    inputBox3 = TinputBox3;
    inputNameRect = TinputNameRect;
    inputQuantRect = TinputQuantRect;
    inputUnitRect = TinputUnitRect;

    if(isViewable == true)
    {
        SDL_RenderCopy(gRenderer, formBackgroundTexture, NULL, &TformBackgroundRect);
        SDL_RenderCopy(gRenderer, inputFieldTexture, NULL, &TinputBox);
        SDL_RenderCopy(gRenderer, inputFieldTexture, NULL, &TinputBox2);
        SDL_RenderCopy(gRenderer, inputFieldTexture, NULL, &TinputBox3);
        SDL_RenderCopy(gRenderer, inputNameText, NULL, &TinputNameRect);
        SDL_RenderCopy(gRenderer, inputQuantityText, NULL, &TinputQuantRect);
        SDL_RenderCopy(gRenderer, inputUnitText, NULL, &TinputUnitRect);
        cancelEntry.render();
    }
    addItemButton.render();
}
void addItemForm::update(int x, int y, SDL_Event e)
{
    if( addItemButton.mouseAction(x, y, e) )
    {
        isViewable = true;
    }
    if( cancelEntry.mouseAction(x, y, e) )
    {
        isViewable = false;
    }
    inputValuestoField(x, y, e);
}
void addItemForm::inputValuestoField(int x, int y, SDL_Event e)
{
    //Detect pressing on rect
    //printf("InputBox.x : %i, inputBox.y: %i", inputBox.x, inputBox.y);
    if( x >= inputBox.x && x <= (inputBox.x + inputBox.w) && y >= inputBox.y && y <= inputBox.y + inputBox.h && e.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN)
    {
        printf("\nHEYHEYHE PRESSING INPUTBOX 1");

    }
    //Start reading keyboard
    //When enter is pressed/clicked away from box stop reading
    //place text which was just input into the appropriate string (name, quantity, unit)


}
void addItemForm::free()
{
    SDL_DestroyTexture(formBackgroundTexture);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(inputFieldTexture);

    SDL_DestroyTexture(inputNameText);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(inputQuantityText);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(inputUnitText);

    addItemButton.free();
    cancelEntry.free();
}

addItemForm::~addItemForm()
{
    free();
    xPos = 0;
    yPos = 0;

    formBackgroundTexture = NULL;
    inputFieldTexture = NULL;

    inputNameText = NULL;
    inputQuantityText = NULL;
    inputUnitText = NULL;

    isViewable = false;

    formBackgroundRect;
    inputBox;
    inputBox2;
    inputBox3;
    inputNameRect;
    inputQuantRect;
    inputUnitRect;

}
```

If anyone is unsure of what I mean to say I am happy to reply to any questions about my code. How I have phrased everything is most likely hard to follow and I am very greatful of anyone who tries to help.

Comment: Why do you list your member variables in the constructor and destructor? A statement such as `formBackgroundRect;` does *nothing* (well it should evaluate `formBackgroundRect` but as the result of that expression is thrown away the compiler will most likely just optimize it away).

Comment: Also, in the `addItemForm::render` function the variables `TformBackgroundRect` (etc.) are ***local*** variables as you redefine them in the function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I didn't include those in the constructor the render function wasn't able to find those variables. I know the `TformBackgroundRect` are local variables however, for some reason  `formBackgroundRect = TformBackgroundRect` doesn't work and I dont know why. Obviously TformBackgroundRect is not null as something is rendered on screen, but it does not transfer its contents. 
I put all the `SDL_Rect` variables in the constructor and did weird things like that because I was not sure what was going on.